# How to start spyder ide?

Tags: python, spyder

I installed Spyder IDE using the exe installer [spyder-2.2.3.win32.exe](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/downloads/list) on Windows 7 , but I can't find the desktop icon. How to start Spyder IDE after installation?

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) I was almost sure our installers created a menu entry and/or a desktop icon (but I haven't tested them in a long time because I work on Linux now). If that's not the case, I'll try to improve the situation for our next release (i.e. 2.3).

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I just ran into the same problem with the spyder-2.3.2.amd64-py3.4.exe installation.

Comment: @ChrisMueller what issue exactly? We create desktop shortcuts now

Comment: Not in the installation I mentioned.  I didn't get a desktop shortcut or a link in the start menu.

Comment: I had to install PySide before spyder was able to run; easy_install -U PySide

Comment: Consider re-opening. You say "Questions about [...] software are off-topic [...] unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." but it seems to me that an IDE is explicitly a programming tool.

Comment: cmd> spyder3 > enter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you install from python(x,y) then it should give you a desktop link, or a start menu link. If you install it from the Spyderlib website, like I did (https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/), then do what I did, assuming you're running windows:

1) Go to the desktop

2) right-click > New > Shortcut

3) Have it open "C:\Python27\Scripts\spyder.bat" (assuming you have python 2.7 installed on your OS) and hit next

4) Type a name for your shortcut and hit finish

This creates a link to open your spyder executable. I'm sorry if it opens a Command Prompt window in the backgroud, that is necessary for Spyder to run.

You can also give it the spyder icon. Do the following:

1) right-click on the shortcut > Properties

2) Click the "Change Icon" button

3) Choose an icon from the system list *or* go to C:\Python27\Scripts and choose an icon from that location (hit "Browse..." to use explorer to get there)

**EDITS**

If you are having trouble getting Spyder to run, try making sure you installed right. Go to https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html to make sure you installed right

Also, Make sure you installed the correct version. If you have python 3.3 installed, the installer for python 2.7 will NOT work. Go to https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/downloads/list to get a list of all the available downloads.

Comment: I tried this, it opens a console and then console disappears, but spyder won't start.

Comment: I can start it with a python module: `from spyderlib import spyder as spyder

spyder.main()`  but i prefer an exe. Why isn't there a spyder.exe?

Comment: It sounds like its crashing. Try to catch a callback or somesuch. Also, make sure qt is installed, I have some vague recollection of needing to install something other than the spyder file.

Comment: Here is the windows installer page: https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/downloads/list
and here is the installation directions: https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/wiki/Installation

Comment: I know this is old, but we have old systems at work.. anyway .. creating a shortcut to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\spyderlib\spyder.py` worked for me

Comment: The last paragraph of the edits is moot, since the most manual way of installing it now, per the pythonhosted instructions, is pip. Whichever version of pip you run will, presumably, install spyder for its corresponding version of python. Hmm--rereading, it looks like that also invalidates the question, at least the .exe part.

Comment: Another way is to look into the scripts folder "C:\python\scripts" for the spyder3.py executable, because they recently renamed it from spyder.py to spyder3.py.  When you find their executable, you can run it by typing spyder3.py from the CLI

Answer (score 2):

I got my link in the start menu:
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python(x,y)\Spyder\Spyder.lnk"
Or you could just look for the executable and create the short cut yourself. Look in Python's installation directory. It's probably C:\Python or something similar. Find spyder.exe, rightclick, create short cut/link, drag link to desktop, done.
Good luck!